# rails migration version number and new model object crazy id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have this crazy label for each time i create a migration that use the time instead of a integer. it makes things very hard to switch between the version of the database that you want to use.
i also have this crazy ID for each object that i create :

## http://poocs.net/", created_at: "2010-03-17  23:02:17", updated_at: "2010-03-17 23:02:17">

How can set up rails to have easy version and id numbers.

thank you

Comment: Sequential timestamps make things easier to revert to an older version of the database, but they make it *very* hard to work on a rails project in multiple branches of a source control system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number is timestamp. Really useful when you have several collaboration in same project.

If you want the old system us that in your environement.rb file

```
   config.active_record.timestamped_migrations = false
```

Comment: what about the the big id number when a model is created?

Comment: The big Id number is the timestamp where migration is made. It's made to avoid conflict if 2 developers made a new migration in same commit. This problem is arrived with DSCM solution.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need to switch between "versions of the database"?
If you mean redoing and undoing a migration, you can do it like this:

```
rake db:rollback
```

Which undoes the last migration, then

```
rake db:migrate
```

To redo it again. You shouldn't need anything else, since migrations should always be done sequentially in the timestamped order.

Comment: rake db:migrate:status helps a lot